# Firefox WeakMap error but not in Chrome and Firefox Developer Edition

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, firefox, mozilla, weakmap

I'm a bit of a beginner in React and I'm wondering why by not using "WeakMap" anywhere I have a problem with it in Firefox browser, but if I run the same React application on Chrome or Firefox Developer Edition, it no longer throws me this error. Did I forget to click some checkbox, is Firefox not adapted, or do I have a lack of knowledge?

I would appreciate a clarification, because I like to know how something works, and Google and ChatGPT are not helping with this topic.

[image: Error displayed on the page]
[image: Error displayed in the console]